# Importance of the binary channel

Tags: information-theory

I know that binary channels work as a building block for large communication channels and they are the simplest to analyze. Apart from them, are there any other reasons why someone would consider a binary channel?

Comment: Don't we live in the *digital* age? DNA may be quaternary, but computers are binary.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? I understand what you are implying. It's like every signal is a combination of bits and in the transmission of bits, we need to consider the binary channel. But would it be possible for you to give me an example?

Comment: What is there to say? The binary channel abstracts away all the engineering. Bit is transmitted. Bit is received, perhaps the wrong one. What is abstracted away: if transmission was across time or space, what modulator and demodulators were used, whether it was transmitted by radio or laser, what the SNR was, etc.

Comment: I think I got it. Thank you

Comment: Also, you can use channels (binary or otherwise) for many things other than communication systems. For example, *bluffing*. Input is what you think. Output is how you act. One can try to infer your thoughts from your actions. You may want to make this very easy or very hard for others to do.

Comment: That's an interesting idea! So, in binary sense, you can simply confuse the other person. And if you want to keep things to yourself, then it can be a very interesting approach

Comment: To minimally confuse others, use a binary channel with transition probability $0$ or $1$. To maximally confuse, use transition probability $\frac 12$.